# Use if statements in Calculate Field Code Block to give features in a field different values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I've been self learning Python. Now I want to play a little with the Python code block so I can be more comfortable building my own expressions later on. Right now I am just playing with this water resource layer. I created the new field called "play", basically what I want to do is write a simple expression so that if the "WETLAND_TY" field holds the value of "Freshwater Forested/Shrub Wetland". the new "play" field will return a value of 1, otherwise it will return value 5.

Below is the screenshot of my current window
[image: The current window]

I don't know what goes wrong here.

I know this issue can be dealt simply with select by attribute. But I am learning to build my expressions for some more complicated projects, so I'd like to finish it with Python expression.

In the process of playing, I made the "play' field like this:
[image]
and changed my code block to:

```
def NewValue(Area):
'''I was playing with a different field: Area'''        
if Area >= 0 and Area < 30000:
    return 1
elif Area >= 30000 and Area < 800000:
    return 2
else:
    return 3
```

And this time it worked. I just don't understand what's wrong with what I wrote the first time.

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first instance, you list `MyChange` as the value for `Play`. The code doesn't recognize this as a function definition, so it's looking for a variable called `MyChange` in the codeblock, but there's no `MyChange` variable outside of the if statement. (I assume -- it might ONLY accept function inputs from the code block based on the error message displayed).

In the second instance, you've created a function via `def functionname(parameters):` which has `return` values. `Play = NewValue(!Shape_Area!)` calls the function, passing the value of the `Shape_Area` field for whatever row it's on in the Field Calculation.

To fix your Wetland Type, just modify it so that you have the codeblock style from the second example process:

```
def NewValue(wettype):
    if wettype == "Freshwater Forested/Shrub Wetland":      
        return 1
    else:
        return 5
```

or you could write it as such:

```
def NewValue(wettype):
    if wettype == "Freshwater Forested/Shrub Wetland":      
        MyChange = 1
    else:
        MyChange = 5
    return MyChange
```

Either way you would now call the function as `Play = NewValue(!WETLAND_TY!)`.

When the variable is within the codeblock, it's just a variable - no need to include the exclamation marks around the variable/field name. When you're inserting the value of a field in Field Calculator/arcpy, you need to include the exclamation marks.

Comment: Thank you so much, both for answering the question and pointing out the mistake I had. I am very new to Python and am just playing with it to gain more experience. So I take it that I have to define a function in the code block to make it work? Simple statements in my first instance wouldn't work?

Comment: Yeah, now that I look at the error message more closely the Field Calculator is explicitly looking for a function definition within the code block.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. Thanks a lot. The reason I'm doing this is because I'm trying to rewrite my colleague's VBScript Code in Python. I can somewhat read the code although I only know a bit Python. His code doesn't seem to have definition of a function. It begins with "Dim Earlier Year, LaterYear, MyChange." Then at the end of each if statement, it shows "MyChange = 2/3/4/5". So I thought that I don't need to actually define a function, rather just assign a value to a random variable. So I guess since ArcGIS Pro only uses Python, I have to play ball? Or did he define a function in VB already?

Comment: I also can read VBScript but not necessarily write it. Python's pretty useful overall so I recommend learning it. If you really want to know the difference in how Python vs. VBScript works in ArcPy search or post a separate question (due to focused nature of site) or check out [Esri documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_89F6A916BFA840528C57210D6B09125D). Or this [Potentially useful article about converting VB to Python](https://sspinnovations.com/blog/useful-scripts-non-programmer-converting-vba-scripts-python/)

Comment: I know this is late reply. But I really appreciate your help. Still learning here.